# How is the entropy created for generating the mnemonic on the Jade hardware wallet?

Tags: hardware-wallet, random, jade

On the Jade hardware wallet/signer how is the entropy created for generating the mnemonic? Where is the code located in Jade repo?

This was asked by [samsam380](https://github.com/Blockstream/Jade/issues/67#issuecomment-1572153756).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [answered](https://github.com/Blockstream/Jade/issues/69) by Jamie Driver in the Jade repo.

> Short answer:
> See this [web post](https://help.blockstream.com/hc/en-us/articles/9640569620761-How-does-Blockstream-Jade-generate-it-s-recovery-phrase-)
>
> Long answer:
> If you opt for new wallet on Jade (ie for Jade to create you a new wallet on-board the hw - always the best option!), [this function](https://github.com/Blockstream/Jade/blob/eeaeb1103ba0e02ef05f778ba13f7846474e6520/main/keychain.c#L256) is called.
> As you can see it gets some entropy whose length depends on how many words you want in your recovery phrase (12-words/128bits is usually considered sufficient, especially if paired with a passphrase, but we also offer 24-words/256bits).
>
> The entropy is obtained by calling [get_random()](https://github.com/Blockstream/Jade/blob/eeaeb1103ba0e02ef05f778ba13f7846474e6520/main/random.c#L136) which gets entropy from the internal random machine.
>
> When Jade starts up, the random machine is seeded with initial entropy from a number of sources/sensors on the chip - temperature, battery/usb current/voltages, radio noise etc. - these environment sensors themselves include a degree of random 'noise' as well as whatever they actually sample. See [here](https://github.com/Blockstream/Jade/blob/eeaeb1103ba0e02ef05f778ba13f7846474e6520/main/random.c#L65).
>
> Also during boot the camera is activated and a number of frames of image data is fed into the random seeding - again even is jade was lying on a desk, the 'black frames' captured would contain random noise. See the boot up code [here](https://github.com/Blockstream/Jade/blob/eeaeb1103ba0e02ef05f778ba13f7846474e6520/main/main.c#L59) and [here](https://github.com/Blockstream/Jade/blob/eeaeb1103ba0e02ef05f778ba13f7846474e6520/main/main.c#L136).
>
> During operation, the internal random machine frequently re-fetches source entropy from the sensors on the chip - temperature, battery/usb current/voltages, radio noise etc. as above (but not the camera) to feed into the machine. See wherever [refeed_entropy()](https://github.com/Blockstream/Jade/blob/eeaeb1103ba0e02ef05f778ba13f7846474e6520/main/random.c#L129) is called.
>
> Additionally at any point the connected application can send in some entropy which jade also throws into its mix of seed entropy. [See here](https://github.com/Blockstream/Jade/blob/eeaeb1103ba0e02ef05f778ba13f7846474e6520/main/process/dashboard.c#L276) (Apps would usually feed in some entropy when they initially connect.)
>
> NOTE: when source entropy is feed into the machine it is always cumulative/additional. We are always 'adding' some more seed randomness, not 'replacing' old data with new data.